# SQL Limit issue with infinite scroll

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function that loads images within a gallery.
Throughout the site it loads the last 20 images, then when a user scrolls down it loads another 20 and works with an infinite scroll code.

However, on one page this does not work and I'm baffled as to why not.

I've narrowed down the problem code to this:

```
function getEachBoardPins($id,$limit=false)
{

    $sql    = "SELECT 
                    *
                FROM
                    pins
                WHERE
                    board_id = $id
                ORDER BY time DESC";
    if($limit)
        $sql .=" LIMIT $limit" ;
    $query  = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

This will load EVERY image within the gallery. Some galleries have in excess of 1000 images so it takes an eternity to load.

By changing the "$limit=false" value to true in the first line only renders the last uploaded image.

Can anyone help me or point me in a kind direction so I can solve it?

thanks.

EDIT:

Infinite scroll code:

```
$(function(){

    // alert($('.pin_item').length);

    var $alpha = $('#alpha');
    $alpha.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $alpha.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.pin_item',
            isFitWidth: true,
            isAnimatedFromBottom: true

            //isAnimated: true
        });
    });
    $alpha.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
        nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : '.pin_item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve

        loading: {

            finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
            img: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/application/assets/images/ajax_loader_blue.gif'
        }
    },

    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $alpha.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
            $("a.act_uncomment").hide();
            $(".enter_comm").hide();
            //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox({scrolling:false,transition:"elastic"});
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });

        });
    }
);

});
```

Comment: What is the function calling this? It looks like one instance of `getEachBoardPins()` being called isn't including a `$limit`. You could also use `$limit = "20"` so that if this happens the user will only be shown 20 instead of all images.

Comment: Yes numeric values work but the infinite scroll is still inactive

Comment: I understand this. The reason it's inactive is because somewhere your code is calling `getEachBoardPins()` without a `$limit` argument. Would you be able to post your ajax code from the page in question?

Comment: The infinite scroll code is about 70 lines long. I'll edit the question with it included.

Comment: Could you also post the html of this element `#page-nav a` from the page which is causing problems. It might be a problem with it which is preventing `$limit` being set.

Comment: Do you know about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?  Your code is vulnerable.

Comment: There is no further inclusions of #page-nav a in the file. It only appears in the JS.
But the same JS is used on other pages and works okay.
I don't know about Injection, is it harmful?

Answer (score 0):

from all of mysql experience limit should be set to an integer and thus will only return a maximum of that many results. try that out with adding a numeric limit to that query

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it, whatever number you pass in will only return the last `$limit` number of records.  If you're querying for more images, you're going to return all the records you already retrieved PLUS the additional records (if you're just increasing that number, for example).

Also, instead of passing `$limit` in as a boolean / integer (mixing data types isn't good practice), maybe you should pass it as a number.  For example:

```
function getEachBoardPins($id, $start=0, $numrows=20)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM pins 
            WHERE board_id = {$id}
            ORDER BY time DESC
            LIMIT {$start},{$numrows}
            ";
    $query  = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

I'm making the assumption you're sanitizing your variables before passing them to your function.

Another way to do it would be to pass in the ID of the last record retrieved.  That way, you can pick up exactly where you left off in case new images have been added since the last time the data was refreshed.

Comment: This works for pulling numbers but the infinite scroll still doesn't appear when I reach the bottom image.

Comment: @Seth-77 You need to keep track of the `$start` and the `$numrows` on the client-side (in the calling JS) so when the bottom of the page is reached it can pass in the last position.

Comment: I've added the JS to the original question. Although I cannot see any correspondence between the JS and function.

Comment: @Seth-77 I was under the impression you wrote the JS.  I think your question is better directed towards the people who wrote Masonry - I have never used it, have no use for it, and don't have time to research it for someone else.